# Json Date to JavasScript Date Conversion problem

Tags: javascript, json, browser, date

Heres the code for converting the json retured date to a string of date.

```
String.toDate = function(stringDate) {
var newDate = new Date(parseInt(stringDate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));
return newDate;
}
```

Here are the details:

Date from the database: 2009-11-18 03:23:25.107
Date Returned by JSON: "/Date(1258514605107)/"
Date Returned by the toDate function :
Wed Nov 18 2009 11:23:25 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)

Web Server and Database server time zone are the same.

Im wondering why the date becomes the current date in my timezone.
Is there anyone here encountered this kind of problem?

Comment: Im sorry, I dont know that thing exists here.. Don't worry at least now Im aware of it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and what about your browser/OS settings ? you need the GMT time ?

I think you get get it with [toUTCString](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_toutcstring) a more complete reference about the [date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) class

```
alert(newDate.toUTCString());
```